# Is possible to edit table inside Stetho database console?

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I´m using an android application and it´s not necessary for me to edit a table on Web, but i would do a lot of tests in my application if it become possible.

A pic of the Stetho database console:

[image: Here´s]

Comment: Select DB you want to edit in left panel. Than command line will appear where you can execute SQL queries.However I don't know if this will work out for Realm.